# bash regex for a file name

Tags: bash, regex

I'm really not that good with regex but I thought I'd be able to pull this off since it's not that difficult.

I'm using find to see if any file that matches the regex exists in that dir. The string will always be the same. The numbers will be different and it will always be .csv

I've tried all sorts of stuff. This is me trying to match the name exactly, and I can't even do that.

```
find /some/dir -name [ String-20160603.csv ]
```

Comment: Try this `for i in /some/dir/with/full/path/*;do a=$(echo $i|grep -E "^/some/dir/with/full/path/String-[0-9]{8}\.csv$");[[ -n $a ]] || echo $a; done`

Comment: Sorry change `-n` to `-z` or `||` to `&&`

Comment: OK, that works. Why can't I just do something like that with find?

Comment: I don't know about `find` I just used it for some times but not as an expert user.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-regex` rather than `-name` as in:

```
find /some/dir -regex '.*-\d{8}\.csv'
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either

Comment: @isea can you elaborate on how it doesn't work?

Comment: The line in my bash file looks like this find /some/dir -regex '.*-\d{6}\.csv' and  when I run the script nothing happens. When I did the find without the regex it would print the path to the file.

Comment: @isea That would be because there are no matches. I've updated my answer to correctly match the file name you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching a single directory, which your question seems to imply, then you can simply use a shell glob:

```
ls String-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv
```